# Draggable / sortable items within a textbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, textbox

I am trying to create a functional textbox with draggable and sortable (jQuery UI) divs inside it. I want the user to be able to write text and have the draggable items shift to the right, just like text would. Here's a mockup of what I am to do:

[image]

Here you see three dropdown menus which can be dragged anywhere in the textbox, and text separating them.

I made good progress on the basic draggable/sortable, but getting them inside a textbox and treated like text is proving much more difficult.

Is this even possible?

[Here is a jsFiddle of my code so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/cenj6htL/)

**And the code:**

```
<div class="demo">
        <div id="sortable" class="ui-state-default">
            <div id="draggable1" class="ui-state-default draggable">
                <select>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>100</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="draggable2" class="ui-state-default draggable">
                <select>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>100</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="draggable3" class="ui-state-default draggable">
                <select>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>100</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

dvdv

```
<style>
    .draggable {
        height: 35px;
    }

    #draggable1 {
        width: 45px;
    }

    #draggable2 {
        width: 150px;
    }

    #draggable3 {
        width: 150px;
    }

    #sortable {
        width: 356px;
        height: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        display: table;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    #sortable > div {
        float: left;
    }
</style>


<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                revert: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few Points:**

1) As your title says "with in a textbox" I see no textbox in your markup

2) If you are going to be writting and changing stuff along with dragging and dropping why not use

```
conteneditable
```

attribute of divs in html that way you can do all actions you would normally do in an `elastic textbox` and still it will be a div

3) and NO! you cant use simple textbox as a container of DOM elements!

see w3schools for `contenteditable` in html

hope it helps